# Scheduling a repeating actor at system startup Play 2.4.3

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, playframework-2.4

I've recently started working in Scala and Play Framework and just upgraded a service I've been working on to Play 2.4.3. My end goal is to create a nightly process that starts up a service method in my play application for the purpose of scheduling events via a method call, which I'm currently calling with an Actor.

I had the basic idea of this working through a Global.scala file with an override onStart, but then I saw the play documentation about moving away from the use of GlobalSettings (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/GlobalSettings) and have been trying to move it to an injected dependency approach.

Here's what I've pieced together so far:

Module Code:

```
import javax.inject._

import com.myOrganization.myPackage.Actors.ScheduleActor
import play.api.libs.concurrent.AkkaGuiceSupport
import play.libs.Akka
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
import akka.actor.{ActorRef, ActorSystem}
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import play.Application

import com.google.inject.AbstractModule

@Singleton
class NightlyEvalSchedulerStartup @Inject()(system: ActorSystem, @Named("ScheduleActor") scheduleActor: ActorRef) {
  Akka.system.scheduler.schedule(10.seconds, 20.seconds, scheduleActor, "ScheduleActor")
}

class ScheduleModule extends AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport {
  def configure() = {
    bindActor[ScheduleActor]("ScheduleActor")
    bind(classOf[NightlyEvalSchedulerStartup]).asEagerSingleton
  }
}
```

Actor Class:

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, Props}
import com.myOrganization.myPackage.services.MySchedulingService

object ScheduleActor {
  def props = Props[ScheduleActor]

  class updateSchedules
}

class ScheduleActor extends Actor {
  val MySchedulingService: MySchedulingService = new MySchedulingService
  def receive = {
    case "runScheduler" => MySchedulingService.nightlyScheduledUpdate()
  }
}
```

Application.conf

```
play.modules.enabled += "com.myOrganization.myPackage.modules.ScheduleModule"
```

The service is calling down to a method that is primarily based on scala logic code and database interactions via Anorm.

Every time I try to start the service up with activator start (or run, once an Http request is received) I get the following error:

```
Oops, cannot start the server.
com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application
```

I've tried running the same code by replacing the Aka.system.scheduler... piece with a simple println() and everything seemed to work fine, meaning the service started up and I saw my message on the console. So I'm guessing there's some dependency that I'm missing for the Akka scheduler that is causing it to blowup. Any suggestions you can offer would be great, I've been banging my head against this all day.

**EDIT (Solved Code Per Request):**

Module Code, with some added code for getting a rough estimation of 3am the next night. This might change down the line, but it works for now:

```
package com.myOrganization.performanceManagement.modules

import com.myOrganization.performanceManagement.Actors.ScheduleActor
import com.myOrganization.performanceManagement.Actors.ScheduleActor.nightlySchedule
import org.joda.time.{Seconds, LocalDate, LocalTime, LocalDateTime}
import play.api.libs.concurrent.AkkaGuiceSupport
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
import akka.actor.{ActorRef, ActorSystem}
import scala.concurrent.duration.{FiniteDuration, SECONDS, HOURS }
import org.joda.time._
import com.google.inject.{Inject, Singleton, AbstractModule}
import com.google.inject.name.Named

class ScheduleModule extends AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport {
  override def configure() = {
    bindActor[ScheduleActor]("ScheduleActor")
    bind(classOf[NightlyEvalSchedulerStartup]).asEagerSingleton()
  }
}

@Singleton
class NightlyEvalSchedulerStartup @Inject()(system: ActorSystem, @Named("ScheduleActor") scheduleActor: ActorRef) {
  //Calculate initial delay to 3am the next day.
  val currentTime: DateTime = DateTime.now
  val targetDateTime = currentTime.plusDays(1).withTimeAtStartOfDay()

  //Account for Daylight savings to an extent, not mandatory that it starts at 3am, just after midnight.
  val initialDelaySeconds = targetDateTime.getHourOfDay match {
    case 0 => new Duration(currentTime, targetDateTime.plusHours(3)).getStandardSeconds
    case 1 => new Duration(currentTime, targetDateTime.plusHours(2)).getStandardSeconds
  }

  //Schedule first actor firing to occur at calculated delay and then every 24 hours.
  system.scheduler.schedule(FiniteDuration(initialDelaySeconds, SECONDS), FiniteDuration(24, HOURS), scheduleActor, nightlySchedule)
}
```

Actor:

```
package com.myOrganization.performanceManagement.Actors

import akka.actor.{ActorSystem, Actor}
import com.google.inject.Inject
import com.myOrganization.performanceManagement.services.PMEvalSchedulingService

object ScheduleActor {
  case object nightlySchedule
}

class ScheduleActor @Inject() (actorSystem: ActorSystem) extends Actor {
  val pMEvalSchedulingService: PMEvalSchedulingService = new PMEvalSchedulingService
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case nightlySchedule =>
        println("Called the scheduler")
        pMEvalSchedulingService.nightlyScheduledEvaluationsUpdate()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well in my case the biggest issue ended up being that when scheduling the actor call in NightlyEvalSchedulerStartup() I was calling Akka.system... which was causing the system to instantiate a new AkkaSystem before the app existed. By removing the akk system was came to represent the injected dependency which was ready to go. Hope this helps someone in the future!

Comment: Could you post the code you ended up settling on to solve this problem?